# JQuery - Automatically changing image width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a website and I have a problem with IE compatibility. My idea to fix this is to have a JQuery script that changes the images width proportional to the window.
However, my script isn't working.

```
$(document).read(function() {
        updateSizes();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            updateSizes();
        })
    });

    function updateSizes() {
        var $windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var $windowWidth  = $(window).width();
        $(".fadingImg").css("width",$windowWidth * 0.7)
    }
```

I have tried adding `+ "px"` to `$(".fadingImg").css("width",$windowWidth * 0.7)`

My JQuery implementation is:

```
<script src="http://abrahamyan.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/jsslideshow/js/jquery-1.4.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: `$(document).read` should be `$(document).ready`

Comment: @user1671639 Thanks! It works! Such a stupid mistake!

Comment: No Problem, But check the console(press F12 developer tools), before posting question.  This will save your valuable time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

not

```
$(document).read
```

Comment: Thanks! Such a simple mistake!

Comment: Yeah! mistakes do happen but we should learn from them and try not to repeat it again :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add px but in the right place

```
$(".fadingImg").css("width", ($windowWidth * 0.7) + "px")
```

You also need to make sure that you have `class="fadingImg"`

You also need to make sure that you put it within a ready block

```
$(function() {
  //code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JavaScript for this solution, why not use CSS?

```
.fadingImg { width: 70%; }
```

Comment: I had that, but it doesn't work with IE for me, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

if your fadingImg is a `<img>`, then try to set the attribute

```
$(".fadingImg").attr("width",$windowWidth * 0.7)
```